# Pageslider.js localStorage.getItem new page load

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am currently using pageslider.js to make a prototype application. I am learning so please bear with me. I have a few pages of content and filled using the primitive html dynamic creation,  one of the pages has a user select option. I can get the values recorded into local storage (according to the console window) but I want to perform calculation and display the values recorded on the next page. This worked well in a fiddle that I created and I understand that this is because the .html was encompassed within a single page so the inner.html method worked but I have no idea of how to implement the same function within this kind of model. Having tried a catalogue of methods I would be grateful if someone could assist or maybe point me in the direction of how to retrieve the values for this purpose. Below is the content of my app.js file. Any help.....Even the inevitable noob slap down is most appreciated.

```
> 
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
new FastClick(document.body);
}, false);

// The dynamically built HTML pages.
var homePage =
'<div>' +
Page1content
'</div>';

var detailsPage =
'<div>' +
'<body>' +
    '<div id = "wrapper">' +
    '<div id = "scroller">' +
    '<div id = "wrapperheader">' +
    '<div id = "contentheader"><a href="#" class="btnleft"><img       src="images/home.png"></a><a href="#page3" class="btnright"><img src="images/pi.png"></a><a href="#" class="contentheader"><img src="images/headerlogo.png"></a></div>' +
            '<div id = "content">' +
            '<div id = "doseinput"><h1>Body Weight<select id="weightselect"><option value="10">10</option><option value="12">12</option>.... value="140">140</option></select></div>' +
            '<div id = "doseinput2"><h1>Dosage<select id="doseselect"><option value="0.1">0.1g/Kg</option><option value="0.15">0.15g/Kg</option><option value="0.2">0.2g/Kg</option></select></div>' +
            '<div id = "doseinput3"><a href="#page4"><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="computeDose()"></div>' +
            '<div id = "footer">' +
            '<p class = "footertextleft"></p>' +
            '<p class = "footertextright">2015</p>' +
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

////output page///

var detailsPage3 =
'<div>' +
'<body>' +
    '<div id = "wrapper">' +
            '<div id = "scroller">' +
            '<div id = "wrapperheader">' +
            '<div id = "contentheader"><a href="#" class="btnleft"><img src="images/home.png"></a><a href="#page3" class="btnright"><img src="images/pi.png"></a><a href="#" class="contentheader"><img src="images/headerlogo.png"></a></div>' +
            '<div id = "content">' +
            '<div id = "weightoutput"><h1>Weight<span id="weight">"weight"</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "doseoutput"><h1>Dosage <span id="dose">"dose"</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output1"><h1>Daily: <span id="output1">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output2"><h1>5 times a week: <span id="output2">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output3"><h1>3 times a week: <span id="output3">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output4"><h1>Twice a week: <span id="output4">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output5"><h1>Once a week: <span id="output5">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "output6"><h1>Once every 2 weeks week: <span id="output6">?</span></h1></div>'+ 
            '<div id = "footer">' +
            '<p class = "footertextleft">UK/HZN/15-0001</p>' +
            '<p class = "footertextright">Date of preperation: January 2015</p>' +
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
    '</div>' +
'</div>';

 //Obtain user inputsvar slider = new PageSlider($("#container"));
 $(window).on('hashchange', route);

 // Basic page routing
 function route(event) {
var page,
    hash = window.location.hash;

if (hash === "#page1") {
    page = merge(detailsPage, {});
//        slider.slide($(page), "right");
} else if (hash === "#page2") {
    page = merge(detailsPage1, {});
//        slider.slide($(page), "right");
} else if (hash === "#page3") {
    page = merge(detailsPage2, {});
//        slider.slide($(page), "right");
}else if (hash === "#page4") {
    page = merge(detailsPage3, {});
//        slider.slide($(page), "right");
}

 else {
    page = homePage;
 //        slider.slide($(homePage), "left");
 }

 slider.slidePage($(page));

 }

 function computeDose() {
 var dose = Number(document.getElementById("doseselect").value);
 localStorage.setItem("dose",dose);
 //  var weight = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("dose"));

 var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weightselect").value);
 localStorage.setItem("weight",weight);
 // var weight = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("weight"));


 //Display result of calculatio

 ////dose     
 document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose) / 7;
 document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose) / 5;
 document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose) / 3;
 document.getElementById("output4").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose) / 2;
 document.getElementById("output5").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose);
 document.getElementById("output6").innerHTML = Math.round(weight * dose) * 2;

 }

//Primitive template processing. 


function merge(tpl, data) {
return tpl.replace()
          .replace()
          .replace();
 }




 route();
```

Comment: add `doseselect.value=localStorage.dose;weightselect.value=localStorage.weight; ` before `route()` at the bottom. feel free to use long-winded dom methods instead of built-in property access.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by this, could you elaborate?

Comment: all you need to do (i think) is set the dropdowns to the localStorage value when the page loads.

Comment: Sorry, this may be naivety but the values selected (page2) seem to be stored in local storage via the onclick command and the computeDose(). Its retrieving them and displaying when the next page (page3) is loaded, I am thinking I may be able to add some script to perform the calculations at that stage but then again I may be way off track......If you think there is a better way of performing then would be more than happy to explore as losing will to live with this currently.

Comment: yes, you store them, but you need to load them too. did i miss that part or did you?

Comment: I think it's possibly me. It's pretty much what I am having trouble with, I am unsure of the event occurs that would allow be to call the value as this is all dynamically generated.